# "Want it to be ready" vs. "want it ready"

Tags: passive-voice

Comparing the following two statements:

```
They want it ready by Monday.
```

and

```
They want it to be ready by Monday.
```

is 'to be' in the latter redundant? Are both correct?

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are equivalent in meaning.

However, there is a *very slight* nuance between them.  The first form is a [flat statement](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flat_2). The second form, using *to be ready* instead of just *ready*, is easier to follow with a qualifying clause. Even if the clause is not present, the possibility of adding one makes the second statement *slightly* less emphatic.

For example:

- They want it ready by Monday unless they inform us otherwise.
- They want it *to be* ready by Monday, unless they inform us otherwise.

Both of these are correct English. However, first sounds “rushed”. The second has a natural pause, and the pause makes it easier for a second person to interject, or for the speaker to follow with additional qualifications. A flat statement is intentionally hard to follow in this way.

Comment: Are you saying adding "to be" makes a speaker tend to pause after Monday?